# Statement: UPDATE `blog_posts` SET `visit` = `visit` + 1 WHERE `id` = 14155 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php code:

```
mysqli_query($link, 'UPDATE `blog_posts` SET `visit` = `visit` + 1 WHERE `id` = ' . $postid . ' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1');
```

in mysqld.log

this error is logged how fix issue?

> [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. The statement is unsafe because it uses a LIMIT clause. This is unsafe because the set of rows included cannot be predicted.

Statement:

```
UPDATE `blog_posts` SET `visit` = `visit` + 1 WHERE `id` = 14155 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, using a `limit` clause in an `update` statement is a dodgy practice, since you can't predict exactly which rows would get updated. Here, however, you're in luck. Assuming the `id` column is really a unique identifier, applying a `=` condition on it will return, at most, just one row, so the `limit 1` clause is just redundant, and you can simply discard it:

```
mysqli_query
($link, 'UPDATE `blog_posts` SET `visit` = `visit` + 1 WHERE `id` = ' . $postid);
```

**Mandatory note:**
Using string manipulation to generate an SQL statement is a dangerous practice, that may leave your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should consider using a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.